# My pen drive not working after I removed unfortunately while it is formating

Tags: mount

When i connected my pen drive it is not showing any icon such that pen drive is connected. I am using ubuntu 16.04. It is not showing even in windows

Comment: I have used testdisk program in similar case and it solved my problems.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

First, see if it's showing up in /dev.  To do this, UNPLUG the device, and type:

```
sudo partprobe
ls /dev/sd*
```

Then, PLUG IN the device and type that command, again.  Notice what's different.  You should have an additional sdX letter, and perhaps some partitions on that device, such as sdX1.  (Replace X with b, c, d, e, etc., as appropriate.)

If you do, indeed, see a new device, that means the device is still working!  Does it have a partition on it (number after the letter)?  If so, that means it's still partitioned, and may still have a formatted, working partition on it.  Let's find out if that's true.  Replace "sdX" with the correct entry, such as, "sdb" or "sde".

```
sudo blkid -d | grep /dev/sdX
```

If something shows up, you will see a filesystem type (like vfat, exfat, fat32, ntfs, ext4, hfsplus, etc.), which means that the partition is showing up as being formatted.  Let's find out if we can actually read that partition.  I'm assuming that you're not using /mnt for anything (by default, it's empty).  If you ARE using it for something, pick a different directory.  As before, replace "sdX#" with something like "sdb1" or "sdd1", as appropriate.  Also replace "type" with the filesystem type you saw with the above blkid command.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/test
sudo mount /dev/sdX# /mnt/test -t type
```

Did that command produce an error?  If so, the filesystem is dead, and you need to reformat it using Gparted or your preferred command-line utility.  If it produced no error message, you can then look in /mnt/test to see what's on the partition.  First, let's assume the mount command worked, and we want to look and see what's in there.

```
cd /mnt/test
ls
```

Are your files and directories there?  If so, great!  If not, you have a blank partition, and, hopefully, you didn't care about anything on that drive...but if you did, you can turn to some forensic tools like testdisk, dd/ddrescue, etc.  There are plenty of forum posts out there on data recovery; Google is your friend (good luck...).  If you have a blank directory, let's just double-check to make sure it's really mounted.

```
mount
```

Do you see your partition (/dev/sdX#) as being mounted on /mnt/tmp?  If so, then you simply have a blank partition.  If you want to be doubly-sure that the partition erased and fully-functional, you can reformat it with Gparted by doing this (see note, below):

```
sudo gparted /dev/sdX#
```

**Note:** you should probably clean up /mnt BEFORE you repartition/reformat/relabel anything.  To do that, close all programs, terminals, and windows that might be using the drive or mount point, and type:

```
cd ~
sudo umount -f /mnt/test
sudo rmdir /mnt/test
```

Then, right-click on the partition and format it as desired.  Alternatively, you can use mkfs.whatever to format it from the command line.  Replace "whatever" with ntfs, ext2, exfat, etc.  I STRONGLY encourage you to read the manual page before attempting this:

```
man mkfs.whatever
```

or

```
man mkfs
```

If you want to be doubly-extra-sure that it's empty and functional, you can create a new disk label, repartition, and then reformat it in gparted (or using your favorite command-line tools, such as parted, gdisk, mkfs.whatever, etc.).

Please keep in mind that, anytime you repartition, create a new disk label (partition table), or format something, if you do that on the wrong drive or partition, you can lose ALL your data!  Be careful, and get it right.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gparted! It usually works for me. Or use lsusb to see what's attached. `fdisk -l` for more info

Comment: Can you please explain how these tools can reveal the USB drive?